# What ways are there to work on a project in a testing environment where the Git commit needs to be different to the PHP code used for testing and dev?

Tags: php, git, netbeans, github

In my project the deployable version needs to have a copy of each of the external libs, a different config file and install and setup files, for security concerns, the main project is set to refuse to run if they are present. Thus the upstream copies of the other projects need to be committed to repo. How can I work on code running on localhost where the file layout and sometimes file contents from dev and testing are different to what I need to commit?

### Background

I am working on a project on hosted on github and my main IDE is netbeans which has imperfect git support (good enough for >99% of my needs). The project is in PHP and uses several other projects as libraries.

As Netbeans does not have the best support for sub-repos I have chosen to keep each additional project in a separate project. This is fine as the central project looks at the config data for where to find these outside libs.

### Half an answer

My instinct is to suppose that there will need to be some "build stage" prior to committing to the github repo but how on earth do I go about setting all that up?

I could write some sort of homebrew thing but then when I pull other people's contributions I would need to reverse the process unless we had a branch for builds and a branch for working copies which seems needlessly complex and could leave the dev(s) config data on public display (not to mention updates being a mess).

I have seen that others have wrestled with somewhat similar problems to no conclusion (at time of asking) ([How to push and pull from github without sharing sensitive information? Smudge & clean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558424/how-to-push-and-pull-from-github-without-sharing-sensitive-information-smudge)) so I am looking for anything that might help me come up with a solution

Comment: Use Composer to handle dependencies, your composer.json can be maintained in the git repo, but use a gitignore to prevent the vendors folder from being included in the repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my main IDE is netbeans which has imperfect git support

Most devs just use the command line. I switch to the NetBeans conflict resolver occasionally, which is very good, but for normal stuff the console is usually faster.

> My instinct is to suppose that there will need to be some "build stage" prior to committing to the github repo
>
> ... unless we had a branch for builds and a branch for working copies

No, there is only ever one repository. It is better to think of your repo as your code history, rather than your deployment state. Branches should just be for features or large changes, which merge into your mainline/master.

There are a good deal of options available to you when deploying. The first is Composer, which Mark points out: when deploying you issue an `install` or `update` command, which fetches the dependencies that satisfy your library requirements recursively. You can use [Bower](http://bower.io/) to do the same thing for your JavaScript dependencies.

Some deployment strategies prefer to build locally and then `scp`/`rsync` to a remote server. Composer and Bower are still probably a good idea, but you write a build script (using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Phing](http://www.phing.info), for example) to create a build copy in a local temporary folder, and then send it to the server. It is common here also to push it to a new release folder on the server, and then swap a symlink or Apache config file when it's ready to go live.

> the deployable version needs to have a copy of each of the external libs, a different config file and install and setup files, for security concerns

Assuming this is a web project, have you tried adding your sensitive environment data to your Apache configuration file? This can be trivially read in PHP, and of course PHP does not care that this information is different according to whether you are developing, testing, demoing a branch or operating live.

---

Further reading: [an excellent PHP deployment book](https://leftnode.org/posts/expert-php-deployments.html), free of charge, that suggests Phing and Capistrano.

Comment: If anyone wants info on per-environment configuration, please ask - I can add a couple of paras about that too.